# Set Firefox Private Browsing as Windows default browser

Tags: firefox, windows-11, file-association, private-browsing

In Windows 11, how do I set the default browser to be Firefox *in Private Browsing*? That is, I want all links launched from other programs to open in a private window in Firefox.

In the Windows 11 settings under "default apps", there seems to be no such option. There are 2 entries for Firefox there, if I click on either of them, it has an option to "Make Firefox your default browser", even though it is already the case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't ever need to use Firefox in non-private browsing mode, you can simply [**set Firefox to always use Private Browsing**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history#:%7E:text=will%20be%20saved.-,Can%20I%20set%20Firefox%20to%20always%20use%20Private%20Browsing%3F,-Firefox%20is%20set).

- Click the ***menu*** button and select ***Settings***
- Select the **Privacy & Security** panel and go to the History section
- Choose Use custom settings for history from the drop-down menu and
  check the **Always use private browsing mode** setting
- Restart Firefox

Now the default browser (which is already set in Windows to Firefox) will be Firefox in Private Browsing mode.

Comment: Not ideal to be stuck always in private browsing, but it works for me.

Comment: @ahon - How is it not ideal?  This achieves exactly what you asked for?

Comment: @Ramhound he wants "Window's Default browser" should always be Firefox Private, but when he wants to use Firefox by opening it manually it should not be Private. Understandable

Comment: I would like to also use non-private mode for manual browsing though.

Comment: @YisroelTech - I understand the question and your answer achieves exactly what the question indicates the author wanted.

Comment: @Ramhound but it also adds an unnecessary and undesirable side-effect.

Comment: @ahon - You should be able to achieve that by launching a specific Firefox profile. There should be multiple answers that explain how to do that. You do understand that  using private mode in Firefox does not prevent tracking cookies or anything like that, the primary function is that the Firefox browser session cannot be restored once it's closed.

Comment: @Ramhound I am mostly interested in the lack of history being stored locally after the session is closed. I have adblock etc for other purposes.
I will look into the profile thing.

Comment: So "Always use private browsing mode" should be a per Firefox user profile setting.  The default browser configuration, I suspect will be limited to just the browser's default user profile, which means you will have to determine which profile you want to be the default

Answer (score 0):

I find that this DOES NOT work.  I am using a video server (UMS) and lately they have changed their interface to web-based, which I understand. It is easier to maintain than creating a windows interface and maintaining it.

But when the server starts it opens Firefox in normal mode, even though I have Firefox set as above to only use private mode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is an Answer or a comment on my solution of using "Always use private browsing mode"? If it's a comment, delete the Answer and put it as a comment (if you can't comment, yet that doesn't make it okay to put it as an answer, perhaps simply ask it as a question with details referencing this answer.)